# Definite Integral of $|\cos^3x|$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Can anyone help me the following integral :
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \left|\cos^3(\theta + \phi)\right|d\theta$$
$\phi$ is a constant. The problem can be easily solved if $\phi=0$, by simply converting into $4$ integrals and considering the sign of cosine in each interval. But how to do it if $\phi$ is not $0.$

Answer (score 3):

You can assume that $\phi$ is zero because you are integrating over a period. In other words, the value of that integral does not depend on $\phi$.

Comment: +1, very clever

Answer (score 0):

One brute force way, very ugly but will work:
$$
\cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b
$$
Now cube both sides and expand the RHS and integrate term-by-term. To apply the absolute value, note that $\cos a \ge 0 \iff \cos^3 a \ge 0$.

Comment: Did you mean $\sin a \cdot \sin b$?

Comment: Brute Force is always our first attempt.

Comment: @AadhaarMurty of course, corrected

Comment: @FelixMarin first does not mean best :)